# I am looking for an efficient way to remove items from a JavaScript array if they are present in another array. Using indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I want to remove those items from `arr_2` which contains the domain name from `arr_1`

```js
let arr_1 = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];

let arr_2 = [
  "domain1.com/about-us",
  "domain3.com/contact-us",
  "domain4.com/privacy-policy",
  "domain2.com/pricing-plans",
  "sub.domain2.com/home-1",
];

let filtered_arr = [];

arr_2.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.indexOf(arr_1) == -1) {
    filtered_arr.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(filtered_arr);
```

i want the result `["domain3.com/contact-us", "domain4.com/privacy-policy"]` from this code, but it prints the whole `arr_2`

Comment: You need to loop over both arrays (one loop inside the other), and you need to use String.includes() instead. Call .filter() on arr_2, then call .some() on arr_1 inside. Give it a try.

Comment: of course filtered_arr is the same as arr_2 - nothing in arr_2 matches arr_1 at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `indexOf` on a string and pass an array as an argument.
You should use `find` to check if `item` has a domain from `arr_1`.
And it's a lot cleaner code using `filter` than `forEach`.

```js
let arr_1 = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];

let arr_2 = [
  "domain1.com/about-us",
  "domain3.com/contact-us",
  "domain4.com/privacy-policy",
  "domain2.com/pricing-plans",
  "sub.domain2.com/home-1",
];

let filtered_arr = arr_2.filter(item => {
  return !arr_1.find(domain => item.includes(domain));
});

console.log(filtered_arr);
```

**Note:** This would also filter out "example.com/domain1.com".

Comment: also i want to remove duplicates from `arr_2` , how can i do it?

Comment: how?
i want to remove duplicates also from this.

`arr_2 = [
        "domain1.com/about-us",
        "sub.domain1.com/post-2",
        "domain3.com/contact-us",
        "domain4.com/privacy-policy",
        "domain4.com/page-1",
        "domain2.com/pricing-plans",
        "sub.domain2.com/home-1",
      ]
`

Comment: `arr_2 = arr_2.filter(...` not removing the duplicates, it prints `['domain3.com/contact-us', 'domain4.com/privacy-policy', 'domain4.com/page-1']`
here `domain4.com` is duplicate
you can see the code here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kazimshah39/skc2djh1/5/).

Comment: I don't see how they are duplicates. Those are different URLs, just same domain.

Comment: I want to keep only one URL from a domain, if there are multiple URLs from the same domain, the first URL should be kept and others should be removed

Answer (score 0):

Your code right now is returning the whole `arr_2` because your filtering logic does not check if each item of `arr_2` contains one of the matching strings in `arr_1`.

`indexOf(arr_1)` is essentially searching each item in `arr_2` for the entire `arr_1` array. The function will always return `-1` because each item of `arr_2` is a string and will never match with the entire `arr_1` array.

I assume you'd want to go through each item in `arr_1` as well, so you should probably do `arr_1.forEach((item1) => { })` inside the `forEach` loop for `arr_2`, and do the `indexOf` check inside this inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive it using `filter` `some` and `includes`

```js
let arr_1 = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];

let arr_2 = [
  "domain1.com/about-us",
  "domain3.com/contact-us",
  "domain4.com/privacy-policy",
  "domain2.com/pricing-plans",
  "sub.domain2.com/home-1",
];

const arr3 = arr_2.filter(url => !arr_1.some(domain => url.includes(domain)))

console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: i want to remove duplicates also from this. `arr_2 = [ "domain1.com/about-us",         "sub.domain1.com/post-2",         "domain3.com/contact-us",         "domain4.com/privacy-policy",         "domain4.com/page-1",         "domain2.com/pricing-plans",         "sub.domain2.com/home-1",       ]`